# Where can this long sentence ending with "won't find it here" be found in "Death in the Afternoon"?

Tags: quote-source

I heard that *Death in the Afternoon* contains a long sentence beginning ​something ​like "Those looking for the Spain" followed by a succession of branching clauses drawing focus to Spain's people, food​,​ and culture ​winding up "won't find it here".

I'm not entirely certain that it's found in this book.  Please tell me the book and chapter where it is.

Comment: Here's a [searchable PDF](https://www.la.utexas.edu/users/bump/images/Hemingway/death_in_the_afternoon.pdf) of *Death in the Afternoon*.

Comment: Thanks! It's much easier than thumbing pages, but I still haven't found it.